# Excel VBA find and replace

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I have this code and it works fine. Now I need change it and I don't know how do it.

The code searsh in entire wordksheet. I need search in only 1 column

the code search entire cell. I need search left or mid or right side of cell.

```
Sub ChgInfo() 

Dim WS As Worksheet 
Dim Search As String 
Dim Replacement As String 
Dim Prompt As String 
Dim Title As String 
Dim MatchCase As Boolean 

Prompt = "What is the original value you want to replace?" 
Title = "Search Value Input" 
Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title) 

Prompt = "What is the replacement value?" 
Title = "Search Value Input" 
Replacement = InputBox(Prompt, Title) 

For Each WS In Worksheets 
WS.Cells.Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, _ 
LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False 
Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the code search entire cell. I need search left or mid or right side of cell."?

Comment: `WS.Columns(1).Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False` Seems like your code already will replace parts of cell content rather than only the whole text. Unless you mean something else by "left or mid or right side"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ?

The below code will look for value in Column A of each sheet.

```
Sub ChgInfo()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Search As String
    Dim Replacement As String
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim MatchCase As Boolean

    Prompt = "What is the original value you want to replace?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

    Prompt = "What is the replacement value?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Replacement = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

    For Each WS In Worksheets
        WS.Columns(1).Replace What:=Search, Replacement:=Replacement, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Next

End Sub
```

**Updated Answer**

```
Sub ChgInfo()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Search As String
    Dim Replacement As String
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim MatchCase As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Dim firstCell As String

    Prompt = "What is the original value you want to replace?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Search = Trim(InputBox(Prompt, Title))

    Prompt = "What is the replacement value?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Replacement = Trim(InputBox(Prompt, Title))

    For Each WS In Worksheets
        Set rngFind = WS.Columns(1).Find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then firstCell = rngFind.Address

        Do While Not rngFind Is Nothing
            rngFind = Replacement & Mid(rngFind, 5, Len(rngFind))
            Set rngFind = WS.Columns(1).FindNext(After:=rngFind)
            If firstCell = rngFind.Address Then Exit Do
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Santosh, this is 50%  now I need find only in the first 4 left characters of cell.

Comment: For example che cell content is:  united-united     i need find the characters unit and replace to aaaa leaving: aaaaed-united

Comment: @RobertoBahia Thanks for giving an example. Give me few minutes

Comment: ok.  other example   cell content  santoshcoolman   search for A and replace for E in the last characters only then the cell content=  santoscoolmEn   leave the first a.

Comment: @RobertoBahia Are you ok to loop ? I am not able to find answer without looping.

Comment: For me no problem. If you have other code I can change all code.

Comment: @RobertoBahia Please try the code in my updated answer & let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I receive error in this line: If firstCell = rngFind.Address Then Exit Do   don't have end if and the exit do is in the same line of IF

Comment: @RobertoBahia Copy the code as it is and it will work for you. If you find it confusing then put an End if which also would work.

Comment: received Run time error 91    the object variable or with block variable not set        in this line               If firstCell = rngFind.Address Then Exit Do

Comment: @RobertoBahia I tried and tested the above code. Its working for me.

Comment: I commit the line and works fine. please explain HOw can I change the code to search in the mid or right of cell

Comment: @RobertoBahia If you can give an example for mid and right...i can give you the solution

Comment: cell content:  RobertABastos   I need select and change only the A in the center of cell string  cell value after change  RobertOBastos

Comment: Example last characters cell content: Main street Delta   I need select  the ELT and change it to ddd  cell after change Main street Ddddta

Comment: Try this `p = InStr(1, rngFind, Search, vbTextCompare) - 1
            aa = Mid(rngFind, 1, p) & Replacement & Right(rngFind, Len(rngFind) - (p - 1 + Len(Search)))
            rngFind = aa`

Answer (score 0):

I used this to replace something somewhere.It's simple but works good for me

```
   Sub test()
Dim x As String, y As String
y = InputBox("Replace what?")
x = InputBox("Replace to?")
    [m12:m20,I2,O7,P5,P6].Replace what:=y, replacement:=x
 End Sub
```