# In Excel how could I change font colour according to content of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, conditional-formatting

I have a list of playing cards with each card in its own cell e.g.
3h
2s
Kd
Ah
Jc....
To help with visualisation I wanted to change the font colour of the hearts and diamonds to red.
Of course manually would be an option, but very tedious

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to write a vba script to do a search and replace using
[Excel VBA find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684155/excel-vba-find-and-replace) as an example.
However as I am NOT changing the text it just looped continually. I also could not make the search format specific.

```
Sub Main()
Dim c As Range
Dim redCell As String

With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A52")
Application.FindFormat.Clear
Application.FindFormat.Font.Color = rgbBlack 'Automatic was a problem
    Set c = .Find("h", LookIn:=xlValues, Searchformat:=True)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        redCell = c.Address
        Do
            Range(redCell).Font.Color = -16776961
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

I also tried to use conditional formatting but could not find a criteria that worked.

```
=OR(FIND("h",A1)=2,FIND("d",A1)=2)
```

generates a #VALUE! error
Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot understand based on what to change the color? I mean, what (different) value should be for the respective cells. conditional formatting should work. What "3h 2s Kd Ah Jc" should mean? I mean, what relevance to have in term of setting the color? Understanding that the strings ending in "h" or "d" are the target of your question and their font must be changed in red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define condtional formatting rules in VBA, e.g.,

```vb
    Sub CondFormat()
    Dim c
    With Range("A1:A52").FormatConditions
        .Delete
        For Each c In Array("d", "h")
            .Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=c, TextOperator:=xlContains
            .Item(.Count).SetFirstPriority
            .Item(1).Font.Color = -16776961
            .Item(1).StopIfTrue = False
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. I chose yours as the answer as I had been trying to make VBA work.

Answer (score 3):

FIND used on the suite character might be a more natural way to do it in combination with worksheet conditional formatting. Something like this:

```
=FIND(Right(A1,1),"HhDd")>0
```

Will return true for any of H h D d and false or #value for everything else.
You can also apply it as a conditional format for that column from:

Home -> Conditional Format

Select A1..A52 and then put that in as a custom rule
It is a bit naughty throwing #value at the conditional format but it works OK.

Rather than having VBA code.

Comment: I don't think it's "naughty" to throw #value. Basically, you use a formula that returns either True (when the cell contains any of the characters) or not. True means apply the formatting. Any other case will be ignored. You should enclose the formula with an IF when displaying the value in a cell, but not for conditional formatting - makes it only more complicated.

Comment: Brilliant solution. My apologies for not marking you as answer, but I very slightly preferred the VBA version as I had tried for so long to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula for your format condition:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("h",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("d",A1)))
```

Your attempt returns an error as `FIND("d",A1)` returns an error (no d found in A1). By using `ISNUMBER` `FIND("d",A1)` will return `false` instead of an error.

Comment: Brilliant solution. My apologies for not marking you as answer, but I very slightly preferred the VBA version as I had tried for so long to make it work. Thank you for reminding me of ISNUMBER

Answer (score 2):

Several good answers already, but just to stay close to your original attempt:

FIND returns an error if the string wasn't found, so your formula always returns an error (since it will never find both `h` and `d`). You can use ISERROR to catch this:

```
=NOT(AND(ISERROR(FIND("h",A1)),ISERROR(FIND("d",A1))))
```

Comment: hmm - this is more or less the same answer as mine ...

Comment: My apologies for not marking you as answer, but I very slightly preferred the VBA version as I had tried for so long to make it work.

Comment: @Ike sorry,  I had read the other answers but somehow missed yours